# NameValueCollection not available from System.Collections.Specialized

Tags: .net, reference, windows-phone, namevaluecollection

In VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone, I am using imports of both `System` and `System.Collections.Specialized`, but I still get an error when trying to use `NameValueCollection`.

Looking in the Object browser, I see it nested within System.dll, but there are several versions of the System dll listed - some of which do not have it.  What I get in auto-complete matches the available items in the System.dll **without** `NameValueCollection`, so I'm thinking I need to sort out which System.dll is being used, but I am not sure how to do so.

Can someone help me to use `NameValueCollection`?

The System versions I have are:
2.0.0.0 (has it) - .NET 2,3,3.5
2.0.5.0 Runtime 2.0.5xxx (does not have it) Silverlight 4
2.0.5.0 Runtime 4.0.3xxx (does not have it) Windows Phone 8
4.0.0.0 (has it) - .NET 4.0

Comment: There's of course only *one* specific version of System.dll on the phone itself.  It is a heavily trimmed version from the ones you'd find back on your dev machine.  It's therefore essential that you use the correct reference assembly in your project so you can't accidentally use a class that's not available.  Like NameValueCollection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NameValueCollection` is not available for Windows Phone. You can use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.