# System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection doesn't exist in target framework

Tags: windows-phone-8, mono, unity-game-engine

I've successfully built and deployed my Unity app for Android, iOS and Blackberry.  When I try to build for Windows Mobile 8, I get the following errors in the build:

System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection doesn't exist in target framework

I've seen solutions

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/192247-System-Collections-Specialized-NameValueCollection-doesn-t-exist-in-target-framework

and

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpapps/error-in-deploying/2a73d0ac-0773-4289-b49f-6b49f2fdf230

which indicate fixing the error is removing some libraries (Prime31, Resharper).   I am not using these libraries, but I am using NameValueCollection in my code in many places.

My understanding of the core problem is that WM8 uses a different version of the .NET framework then does Unity/Mono.

Is there a project setting that I can sync these? or  a way I can use to link in this library, if not, worst case, is there a substitute I can use for NameValueCollection?

(update)
I can reproduce this using an empty project which contains an empty game object holding the following script:

```
 void Start() {
   NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
   nvc.Add("asdf","blah");
 }
```

Comment: Although this probably doesn't help you one bit, I was able to use NameValueCollection in a fresh Win8 Unity project with default settings, namely with API Compatibility level set to .NET 2.0 Subset.

Comment: @HappyApple may I ask what version of Unity you are using?

Comment: 4.3 Pro latest, though this feature's been in Unity for a long time and the version of Mono hasn't changed.

Comment: Looks like `NameValueCollection` is not available on Windows Phone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348158/namevaluecollection-not-available-from-system-collections-specialized

Comment: Thank you all for the help, it does indeed appear that NameValueCollection is not available on WP8